# python3 function to merge dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, hash-map

I have a bunch of JSON records, each record with a varying degree of completeness. In other words, record A may contain keys not in record B, and vice-versa. To get a better understanding of the data within, I have created a function to take N number of records and merge them together, creating one single frankenstein record containing all keys and a single value for each key.

```
import sys
import json
def frankenstein(out, in_dict, key=None):
    if isinstance(in_dict, dict):
        for k, v in in_dict.items():
            if isinstance(in_dict[k], list) and v:
                out.setdefault(k, [])
                frankenstein(out[k], v, k)
            elif isinstance(in_dict[k], dict) and v:
                out.setdefault(k, {})
                frankenstein(out[k], v, k)
            elif v:
                out[k] = v
    elif isinstance(in_dict, list):
        s = {}
        for item in in_dict:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                frankenstein(s, item)
            elif not out:
                out.append(item)
            if s:
                if not out:
                    out.append(s)
                else:
                    frankenstein(s, out[0])
                    out[0] = s
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [
        {
            "name": "foo bar",
            "experience": [
                {
                    "company": {
                        "name": "oracle",
                        "hq": "123 main st",
                        "size": 100
                    },
                    "function": [
                        {
                            "name": "go getter"
                        }
                    ],
                    "location": {
                        "doubleday": "publisher"
                    },
                    "animal": "horse"
                }
            ],
            "skills": ["programming", "eating"]
        },
        {
            "name": "poo dar",
            "experience": [
                {
                    "company": {
                        "name": "microsoft",
                        "url": "foo.bar/com"
                    },
                    "function": [
                        {
                            "name": "bread",
                            "level": "really high"
                        }
                    ],
                    "solitary": {
                        "fat": "cat"
                    },
                    "health": "no good"
                }
            ],
            "skills": ["igz"]
        },
        {
            "name": "poo mar",
            "experience": [
                {
                    "function": [
                        {
                            "zoo": "creature"
                        }
                    ],
                    "location": {
                        "taste": "food"
                    },
                    "ping": {
                        "pong": "bong"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "skills": ["woots own"]
        }
    ]
    out = {}
    for item in l:
        frankenstein(out, item)
    print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

#### This is the output from the code:

```
{
    "name": "poo mar",
    "experience": [
        {
            "function": [
                {
                    "name": "bread",
                    "level": "really high",
                    "zoo": "creature"
                }
            ],
            "location": {
                "taste": "food",
                "doubleday": "publisher"
            },
            "ping": {
                "pong": "bong"
            },
            "company": {
                "name": "oracle",
                "url": "foo.bar/com",
                "hq": "123 main st",
                "size": 100
            },
            "solitary": {
                "fat": "cat"
            },
            "health": "no good",
            "animal": "horse"
        }
    ],
    "skills": [
        "programming"
    ]
}
```

I've tested the function and it does work. What I'd like is some feedback with regards to the code. Am I doing this in the most efficient way possible? Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: This question is probably answered by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o

Comment: @user985366 None of the answers in the linked question on SO cover a deep merge, and none of them deal with nested lists of dicts like this code. Beyond that, I don't believe this question is asking how to do it, since they obviously achieved their desired goal; but rather, it's asking for a code review on their code, which seems to be the obvious intention of this community.

Answer (score 5):

The `key` parameter to `frankenstein()` does not appear to be used anywhere and can be eliminated.

Use blank lines to split the code up into smaller logical chunks.  It aides reading and understanding the code.

`in_dict` is a misleading name, because it can be a list, dict, or something else altogether.

In the `for k, v in in_dict.items():` loop, `in_dict[k]` and `v` are the same thing, `v` is tested 3 times, and the return value of `setdefault()` is discarded then looked up on the next line. It can be rewritten it like so:

```
    for k, v in in_dict.items():
        if not v:
            continue

        if isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
            out_k = out.setdefault(k, v.__class__())
            frankenstein(out_k, v)

        else:
            out[k] = v
```

The logic for handling `lists` seems convoluted. For example, it looks like `s` can get updated each time through the loop and also appended to `out[k]`. The question doesn't clearly state the rules for combining things, so maybe it's correct.  A comment or doc-string explaining the purpose of the function and the rules for merging values would be helpful.